# Reference request for the "Parseval theorem for convolution"

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

This is a reference request. It is motivated by understanding an online article [here](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/calculus-editorial/82159).

In evaluating an integral,
it is written in [the explanation](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/calculus-editorial/82159) that one can use the "Parseval's theorem for convolution" which is
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) g(x)\; d x=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} F_{c}(\omega) G_{c}(\omega)\; d \omega\tag{1}
$$
where
$$
F_{c}(\omega)=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \sin (\omega x) d x\;.
$$

I see no "convolution" in (1) unless one write $g(x)=h(t-x)$ by defining $h(x):=g(t-x)$. I suspect that it is a misnomer. The form of (1) is nevertheless very close to that of the version in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Statement_of_Parseval%27s_theorem). Anyway, I am more interested in knowing when and why exactly (1) is true.

I have (very!) limited knowledge in Fourier analysis and I believe the Parseval theorem is a well-known result but different books treat it rather differently depending on how Fourier transform is introduced. I am looking for a **book** that has a theorem and its proof for (1), *or* a theorem stated in the form that has (1) as its easy consequence.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I agree with you that the use of "convolution" as part of the title of Parseval's theorem is wrong.

Comment: I think if you apply Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ to the linked Wikipedia version of Parseval's theorem, you will recover this sine-Fourier transform version, but I may be overlooking some details.